# UDP socket connection in flash actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets, udp

is it possible to create a UDP socket connection in flash ? I know RTMPF but it doesn't provide access to UDP. I know that in AIR its possible, but im looking for a 'flash' sollution.

thank you

Comment: Flash only supports TCP connections out of the box...someone claims that had a UDP communication working on flash thou. http://www.kongregate.com/forums/4/topics/49058?page=1

Answer (score 3):

**No.** UDP Socket is AIR only.